# How to send HTTP header and HTTP body separately using socket?

Tags: http, c++11, tcp, http-headers

I can send both header and body this way,

```
std::string complete_response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 13\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\nHello, world!";

socket.send(complete_response);
```

But I'm lost when it comes to sending them at separate stages. I've attempted the following and it doesn't seem working at all,

```
std::string header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 13\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
std:string body =  "Hello, world!";

socket.send(header);
socket.send(body);
```

Using Wireshark, I see that the browser get the header part then browser close the connection and not wait for the body.

Comment: What type is `socket`? Sounds like `socket.send` does something more than just transmit the bytes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it's TCP. I however curious about the HTTP format that I am using to send.

Comment: HTTP response format looks OK to me (except that usually `Content-Type` header is also provided, e.g. `Content-Type: text/plain`). There shouldn't be a difference between sending the two parts with a single call or two separate calls. That's why I suspect that the class you use does something in `send` besides just sending the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is very common in JS.
You can use the below example calling from Chrome's console or Node REPL interface.

```
async function postData(url = '') {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
          'Content-Length': 'application/json'
          
        },
        body: JSON.stringify( <BODY DATA>)}) 
      });
      return response.json(); 
    }

postData('<URL>')
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res); 
  });
```